# Pgocaml customizing sql queries

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a query that simply drops a table.

```
  let drop_table dbh table_name =
    let query = String.concat " " ["drop table"; table_name] in
    PGSQL(dbh) query
```

I am receiving the following error from the query

```
File "save.ml", line 37, characters 10-11:
Parse error: STRING _ expected after ")" (in [expr])
File "save.ml", line 1:
Error: Preprocessor error
```

Why am I getting this error? It appears that this function is valid Ocaml syntax.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot construct `query` when using PG'OCaml's syntax extension. You must provide a literal string. This is the tradeoff for getting PG'Ocaml's compile time query validation. If `query` could be any OCaml expression, PG'OCaml wouldn't know how to validate it at compile time.

Personally, I've stopped using the syntax extension completely. My feeling is it doesn't scale to large projects. Instead I call `prepare` and `execute` directly. For example, this function will create a new database connection (assuming the connection parameters are previously defined), run the given query, and close the connection:

```
let exec query =
  let db = PGOCaml.connect ~host ~user ~database ~port ~password ()  
  PGOCaml.prepare db ~query ();  
  let ans = PGOCaml.execute db ~params:[] () in  
  PGOCaml.close db;  
  ans
```

Of course, this isn't a robust implementation and shouldn't be used in production code. It doesn't handle errors and isn't asynchronous.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a query you are using, and then how you are compiling it? In the context of the question I asked would be phenomenal!